# Uniqueness for inhomogeneous solution from fundamental solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, distribution-theory, fundamental-solution

I am looking at the differential operator
$$ L := \Delta^2-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \ \ .
$$
I have found a fundamental solution $F_L$ and know that the inhomogeneous solution $L u = f $ can be described by $$ u := F_L * f \ \ .$$
However I don't know how to find conditions that make this problem unique? Is there a general strategy for this, or is it specifically tied to the operator?

Comment: Keep in mind that once you find one $u$ such that $Lu = f$, any $v$ such that $Lv = f$ satisfies $L(v - u) = 0$. So it suffices to find conditions which make the solution to $Lw = 0$ unique, since any solution $v$ can be written as $u + w$ for some $w \in \ker L$. There are many boundary cases which result in a unique solution to the homogeneous wave equation.

Comment: To be well-posed you typically would expect a boundary/radiation condition to be satisfied as well as some level of smoothness of the boundary itself and the initial conditions. As it stands you can add any constant to $u$ and still have a solution.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSaving ! But I would need more conditions than for the wave equation wouldn't I?

Comment: There's typically no general strategy for uniqueness. Usually growth estimates like the Maximum principle for the heat equation will get you pretty far, but in more complicated PDEs proving uniqueness can be difficult or even impossible (e.g Navier Stokes.)

Comment: Proofs for uniqueness also generally differ based on whether you are concerned with an IVP or BVP - which is more important to you in this case?

Comment: @K.defaoite To be honest I have no intuition of what this does physically, so either initial or boundary value problem is fine, and I would try to tackle the problem which iseasier